# Creating Custom Design and Saving Canvas to JPEG

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

My wpf application loads some images and presents them in a canvas, when all images have been loaded I am saving that canvas to a jpeg.  But sometimes it does not get all of the images that have been loaded!  Is there  a way that I can force the Canvas to render before I do the save to jpg process?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling InvalidateVisual?  That should cause it render again.

```
myCanvas.InvalidateVisual();
```